# ExportHeader property on Query Viewer does not work

Tags: genexus

On a Web Panel that has a Query Viewer Control, I set the following properties on the Start Event:

> QueryControl.ExportHeader = " src='http://www.inalambrik.com.ec/wp-content/themes/inalambrik-theme/img/logo-inalambrik.png'
>   width='1000' height='150'/>" QueryControl.ExportHeaderHeight = 150

But when I export a pivot table to PDF, the header does not appear.

I´m using JavaScript as renderer with Genexus Ev2 U7

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not implemented for the javascript render.

Regards.